# Using permute with glossaries

Tags: errors, indexing, glossaries

There is a problem with using the package `permute` with `glossaries`.

**A minimal working example:**
(by the way a minimal *working* example to show how an "index of notation" can be created)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{permute}
\usepackage[style=long3colheader]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{root}{name=\ensuremath{\sqrt{(12)}},description={a square root}}

%% uncomment the following line and the problem appears
%\newglossaryentry{permutation}{name=\ensuremath{\pmt{(12)}},description={a permutation}}

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
Permutations in the text work well $\pmt{(123)(45)}$.
\glsaddall
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

If the Perl script "makeglossaries" is available, run this with:

```
pdflatex filename
makeglossaries filename
pdflatex filename
```

Uncommenting the line in the source code leads to:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pmt@GetPrintArgs #1->\let \pmt@order [...]
```

Is there a possibility to use `\pmt` in the glossary? Using the package option `sanitize=none` does not help. <del>Enclosing `\pmt{...}` with `\protect` did not help.</del>

The **solution** is simply, as egreg pointed out, to write

```
\protect\pmt{...}
```

*without* braces. Note that `\protect{\pmt{...}}` *with* braces does *not* help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `\protect` in front of `\pmt`:

```
\newglossaryentry{permutation}{
  name=\ensuremath{\protect\pmt{(12)}},
  description={a permutation}
}
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks! The problem was that `\protect` must be used without braces. I've included the answer above.