# How to write a permutation?

Tags: math-mode, matrices

How to write a permutation like this ?

[image: permutation]

Comment: do you know how to utilize the `pmatrix` environment from  `amsmath` package

Comment: Related: [Typesetting permutations with LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65496/5764)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider using [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `smallmatrix`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\[
  a = \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n-1 & n \\
    2 & 3 & 4 & \cdots &  n  & 1
  \end{smallmatrix}\bigr)
\]
Here is another permutation $a = \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n-1 & n \\
  2 & 3 & 4 & \cdots &  n  & 1
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ in text mode.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `amsmath`'s `pmatrix` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  a = 
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n-1 & n \\
    2 & 3 & 4 & \cdots &  n  & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Another solution with `matrix`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  a =
  \left(
  \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n-1 & n \\
    2 & 3 & 4 & \cdots &  n  & 1
  \end{matrix}
  \right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered a package specific also to write also permutations. This package is available on this site https://ctan.org/pkg/permute. I did not know it but it can be useful for other users.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{permute}%%%% <-----https://ctan.org/pkg/permute
\begin{document}
In this case I have used permute package in math-mode:
\[
a=\pmtid
\pmtdo{(\cdots)}
\pmtdo{1{2} 2{3} 3{4} {n-1}{n} {n}{1}}
\pmtvprint[1 2  3 \cdots {n-1} n] 
\]
In text-mode we have:
$a=\pmtid
\pmtdo{(\cdots)}
\pmtdo{1{2} 2{3} 3{4} {n-1}{n} {n}{1}}
\pmtvprint[1 2  3 \cdots {n-1} n]$ similar a smallmatrix option.
\end{document}
```